# Why is this MySQL insert so slow?

Tags: mysql, optimization

```
CREATE  TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `church` (
  `church_id` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT ,
  `name` VARCHAR(40) NOT NULL ,
  `city_id` SMALLINT(4) UNSIGNED ZEROFILL NOT NULL ,
  `validated` TINYINT(1) NULL ,
  PRIMARY KEY (`church_id`) ,
  INDEX `church.city_id-city.city_id_idx` (`city_id` ASC) ,
  UNIQUE INDEX `church-city_id` (`name` ASC, `city_id` ASC) ,
  CONSTRAINT `church.city_id-city.city_id`
    FOREIGN KEY (`city_id` )
    REFERENCES `city` (`city_id` )
    ON DELETE RESTRICT
    ON UPDATE RESTRICT)
ENGINE = InnoDB
DEFAULT CHARACTER SET = utf8
```

I have this table `church` on my localhost (laptop). When I do an insert on it (it has `10` rows right now), it takes 160ms.

- The church_id is used as a foreign key in other tables.
- The name and city_id should together be unique.
- The city_id is a foreign key

Isn't this a but much, and have I done something wrong?

Comment: @juergend Yes, I would think so too, but are the indexes overly complex or unneccecary? I've used databases for a couple of years, but I never thought about performance because it was all just for fun.. But now I see others complaining about 40ms! So I started wondering.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Inserts have to do quite a bit of work:

- Lock the table
- Check unique index constraints
- Check foreign key constrains
- Write the new record
- Update indexes
- Unlock the table
- Write the transaction log

Comment: +1! I have an AJAX which inserts a row, it then selects for that same row again to find the auto-generated ID to send back to the user. Do you know if there is any way of getting the generated ID without doing a select?

Comment: Since it takes 160ms just for the INSERT, I'm looking for ways to improve the speed.

Comment: @Student: use [`LAST_INSERT_ID()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/information-functions.html#function_last-insert-id)

Comment: Use `mysqli_insert_id()` (or whatever is equivalent in the API you're using) to get the last auto-increment ID. If you're doing lots of inserts in a row, you can speed it up by putting them all in one transaction.

Comment: Thanks! I did a quick search for that in PDO, but I only found articles describing the next auto_increment_id..

Comment: @StudentofHogwarts - PDO::lastInsertId() or you can query MySQL directly using what ypercube said.

Comment: @Barmar: The entire table is not locked exclusively, only with an intention lock.

Comment: @ypercube Whether the lock is exclusive or not doesn't matter, it still takes time to set it.

Comment: Yes, I did $db->lastInsertId() :)